# single table parent child relationship query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have written a query to get the items from the table which doesn't have any child items. It's working fine but is very slow.
Any better/easier/optimized way to write the same thing?

```
select distinct id, (select count(i.item_id) from order_item as i where i.parent_item_id = o.item_id) as c
from order_item as o
where product_type = 'bundle'
having c = 0
order by id desc
limit 10;
```

Few of the fields are these to get the idea of a structure

```
Table: order_item
Columns:
item_id PK
order_id
parent_item_id
product_id
product_type


item_id  | order_id | parent_item_id | product_id | product_type
-----------------------------------------------------------------
   1     |    1     |     null       |     1      |   bundle
   2     |    1     |       1        |     2      |   simple
   3     |    1     |       1        |     3      |   simple
   4     |    1     |     null       |     4      |   bundle
   5     |    2     |     null       |     1      |   bundle
   6     |    2     |       5        |     2      |   simple
   7     |    2     |       5        |     3      |   simple
```

Query should only return the 4rth item

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results to explain what you mean by "child items".

Comment: @GordonLinoff question updated. please take a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below. Also consider creating indexes on `PARENT_ITEM_ID` and `ITEM_ID`

```
SELECT OI.*
  FROM ORDER_ITEM OI
       LEFT JOIN ORDER_ITEM OI2
          ON OI2.PARENT_ITEM_ID = OI.ITEM_ID
 WHERE OI.PRODUCT_TYPE = 'bundle' AND OI2.PARENT_ITEM_ID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest `not exists`:

```
select oi.*
from order_item oi
where oi.product_type = 'bundle' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from order_item oi2
                  where oi2.parent_item_id = oi.item_id and oi2.product_type = 'bundle'
                 )
order by id desc
limit 10;
```

For performance, you want an index on `order_item(parent_item_id, product_type)`.

Note:  I'm not sure you want the `product_type` filter in the subquery, but it is the logic your query is using.

Comment: it's returning the correct results after changing the inner query product_type condition. I have edited the answer

Comment: however, the performance has little to no difference

Comment: @AhmedJaved . . . Do you have the recommended index?

Comment: no, but the ismetguzelgun's query worked fast enough without adding new index. Actually the table is a production site table and is sized around 6GB. So can't make any change to it